# Using smtp with recipientList in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use SMTP component inside recipientList.

```
.recipientList(simple("smtps://smtp.gmail.com?username=abc@gmail.com&password=RAW(abc)&to=${header.alertTo}&subject=RAW(alert)"));
```

When the value of ${header.alertTo} is just a single email address, this works. However, if it is comma separated list of address it throws exception.

```
No endpoint could be found for: def@gmail.com&subject=RAW(Alert), please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar. and the stracktrace is org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: def@gmail.com&subject=RAW(Alert), please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.resolveEndpoint(ExchangeHelper.java:85)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor.resolveEndpoint(RecipientListProcessor.java:223)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor.createProcessorExchangePairs(RecipientListProcessor.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:208)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:112)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
```

I was earlier using "to" to send these mails. That works fine. But later due to a change involving configurable email addresses for different routes I have to use recipientList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the delimiter char in the recipient list to something else than comma.

See the documentation for how to do that

- http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Comment: Thanks Claus. I found it out just a min back. Was about to answer it myself :). Thanks though. This works fine.